# Are there people who aren't destined to be runners(competive or leisure but not pro) and others not ? If not why?

Tags: running-training-plan

I am pretty athletic for a female. I've always wanted to run outside regularly outside in all seasons and haven't yet. On a side note I joined a running room "beginners" group which wasn't so and as the frigid air went in my lungs I could stay... But that's another story.

As a pre/ teen i would get those side cramps which led me to believe I could never run. It was discouraging, disappointing and embarrassing. I tried to ignore it but no change. More recently I tried and just like that I began... I started getting the runners high and love it.

I don't seem to gave the experience or confidence to pursue this to its fullest. I would love some advice. I am agile quick but still think I have slow twitch fibers, I detest intervals, all I think is that keeping my heart rate up is good. What training on a treadmill do you suggest. Time , incline, speed, warm up, pee and post stretch, eating, water intake pre during post, protein etc, x per week. I can run at 3.4-5 and maintain for 10 plus min. I drink alot of water. I try to eat a small amount before. I wish I could feel great about my progress and stretch tight muscles after. I get distracted and feel discouraged when I see other runners who go 8 km without effort. I am 260 and close to 5'10. Bigger bones and bike as well at the gym. My goal is to be a pretty good runner/ jogger ( as I think anyone should being the most natural and free movement we can do) to be energetic and to not be beat for possible athletic endeavour. Also I want to be the most fit in my life, challenge myself and push myself .

Thanks to everyone who helps me.

Comment: First, a slight misconception. "Bigger bones" is an excuse. You may have a taller frame at 5'10" than most females, but that is a very small (in the order of a pound or two) difference from someone that is 5'4" as far as bone size/weight. At your height and weight, you are morbidly obese. Your first order of business is a doctor visit and weight loss. I'm sorry to be so blunt, but you need to worry about basic health and weight first. Once you get that under control, I would recommend a couch to 5k program, and progress from there.

Comment: A couch john p???      Looking at my its fair i m obese not morbidly thank you very much mr doctor. I gym 5 days a week, and plan on loosing in total 50- but you did not ask and you did not know.

Comment: A difference between a small frame and a big frame is way bigger than a pound or two. Sure, it's not as big as for men, but it is not that small.

Comment: @s3v3ns - Read what I wrote. Bone weight differences from small to medium to large is not as big as people think it is. Yes, larger frame people weigh more, but that is more due to larger muscles and other flesh than it is due to the bones themselves. A femur that is 18" long is very close in weight to a femur that is 22" long.

Comment: @user13232 - I'm sorry you don't like it, but that's the classification you fall under. Morbidly obese is classified as 100 lbs over ideal weight, BMI of 40+, or BMI of 35+ with health problems. Even for a "large frame", your ideal weight is listed as 149-170 as a 5'9" female. (Close to 5'10 still puts you as 5'9). So even at the top end of the chart, you are 90 lbs overweight, and a bmi of 36. That either puts you as morbidly obese or teetering on the edge of it. The "couch to 5k" is a common running program for people to get to a basic running fitness from nothing. It's a name, nothing more.

Comment: Mr john p im pretty much 5'10 tight - and im undr 50 lbs . Get a life

Comment: @user13232 - I'm just trying to get you to admit facts. You are a 5'10" female that is 260 lbs. By every calculator or chart out there you are either morbidly obese or teetering on the edge of it. If you face reality rather than perception, you will be happier and healthier in the long run. I wish you luck on your journey.

Answer (score 0):

I will give you an vague answer.
Since, as you stated, you think you have good slow-twitch fibers, which should make you a good marathon runner. The best way to find out, in what area you are better is to run 100 m. How fast were you? How do you feel?. That will give you your answer.
There is [this](http://running.competitor.com/2014/07/training/the-role-of-muscle-fibers-in-running_82416) good site, where you can learn more about different kinds of muscle fibers, and how they work.

As for eating. Just eat healthy. I strongly believe in "If it fits your macros". There are some good calculators online to figure out your macros. Just fill them with some healthy foods, and occasionally(not more than once a week or two) reward yourself with something dirty(if you want), but make sure you are not going over your macros.
A great site, to track them is [myfitnesspal](http://myfitnesspal.com).

As for the "I feel discouraged". How do you think they started? Do you think they woke up one day and just ran 8 km without any effort?. No. Running is something that requires dedication. I was always good at short bursts, one of the best in my school day, but i never was first in marathon running, because i did not even care for it. 
Oh, and i was almost 100 kg and 190 cm tall.
Do outdoor running as much as possible(but do not over do it of course). It is way better than treadmill in every way. If you want to be a jogger you have to be ready for everything, from downhill to uphill. That is why outdoors is better. Run to different places, enjoy the weather etc.

Depending on what your goals are, you can train in one or the other area. Do not feel embarrassed. You are already doing more than most, you should feel proud for wanting to do something like this.

Your goals are there, fulfill them, and do not let anyone judge you. Push yourself and one day, you also can run 8 km without even breaking a sweat.

The only limits we have, are the ones we set ourselves.

Comment: Thank you . I wish i had time to thoroughly answer just not now. Weekend for sure.